# Discord Modal Form Body Issue?

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\modal.py", line 186, in _scheduled_task
    await self.on_submit(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\pacif\OneDrive\Desktop\Essence Discord\Cogs\arcane.py", line 128, in on_submit
    await interaction.response.send_modal(Editor())
  File "C:\Users\pacif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 852, in send_modal
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Users\pacif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 221, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In type: Value must be one of {4, 5, 6, 7, 10}.
```

A modal, after taking an input sends a new modal which is having issues.

I wanted it to send the new modal and allow you to send new inputs. Nada

Code: https://pastebin.com/cPuXJVCK

Comment: You need to include your code, just saying that there's an error isn't enough information to help

Comment: Sorry, here https://pastebin.com/cPuXJVCK

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: Questions must be adequately self-contained. Putting the relevant code on another web site is not acceptable. You're expected to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.